# Firebase Auth not working, but is for friend, swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

A friend and I are working on a simple iOS app and were trying to implement some firebase functionality such as login/signup capabilities. My friend set up our firebase account and wrote the code as seen here:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(_ sender: Any) {

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email_text.text!, password: pass_text.text!) { (user, error) in
            if user != nil {
                //user exist
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeToQuestionSegue", sender: nil)
            } else {
                self.error_label.isHidden = false
                print("no")
            }


}
}

@IBAction func signupButton(_ sender: Any) {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email_text.text!, password: pass_text.text!) { (user, error) in
            // ...

        }

}
```

This all works for him on his computer. However, when I tried pulling the project off GitHub and made some UI changes, the code does not seem to connect with Firebase i.e. nothing happens. I pulled the GoogleService-Info.plist file from our firebase account. Are there any other steps that I am supposed to be doing? Any help/tips with Firebase is appreciated.

Comment: Did nothing really happen? Put a breakpoint there to see if `loginButton` is really called.

Comment: I believe i just tried putting it in and the simulator stopped after pressing the login button. When i read the console output, I do see a "Firebase Analytics enabled" message within everything else.

Comment: So which branch of the if statement did it go? Did it reach `performSegue` or `print("no")`?

Comment: I'm not too sure if i'm putting the breakpoint correctly, but without it i always get "no" printed.

Comment: I see. One possibility is that you did not enter the email and password correctly. Ask your friend for the correct password and email or try creating a new user and then log in.

Comment: We have tried all different ways. Does Firebase work differently when there are multiple users working on it? Do i need my own "key" or something, or could it be a problem with the GoogleService-info.plist file? It was not there originally when I grabbed the files off github

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I know what the issue is.

Firebase is working with "Cocoapods." 
Maybe you have to install them on your PC too.

In order to use Firebase, you need the whole Project Folder (not only `.xcodeproj`, Appfolder...). You have to use `.xcodeworkspace` and you need all Data for Firebase (Pods Data and Folder, Google Plist file, ...)

I hope it will work.